# How do I run the test after completing all the tests? (

Tags: python, pytest

There are several tests in the tests folder: test_first.py , test_second.py .
Each test checks the operation of the site by creating and modifying projects. I need that, regardless of how I run the tests `tests/test_first.py` or `tests/` upon completion of all tests, the `delete_prj` function is executed, which deletes the created project after the tests have run. I'm not asking for the task execution code, the answer to the question is enough

Comment: Would a session scoped fixture do what you want?

Comment: Maybe there is something for `conftest.py` ?

Comment: @Sören yes, it will be one session to which the work of the tests will be linked. Everything will happen with the help of selenium

Answer (score 2):

Use a session scoped fixture. Something like this:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope="session")
def do_stuff_after_everything_is_done():
    yield
    delete_prj()
```

(untested)